# Find out if process is running in a cmd.exe or PowerShell window

Tags: windows, powershell

Imagine you're writing a program in a high level language where you are not allowed to do custom system calls (win32 API) because code is cross compiling or the language doesn't support that.

When your process is running on windows, is there a way to find out if you're running inside powershell and not cmd.exe? Or vice versa?

I'm trying to print "I'm running in powershell" and "I'm running in cmd.exe" from the program.

In this case I'm writing the program in Golang but that shouldn't really matter because I don't want to traverse process tree.

Comment: Your program is never running *in* cmd.exe or powershell.exe. Do you mean you want to determine the parent process (e.g. cmd.exe, powershell.exe, explorer.exe, etc)? Do you have the ability to run programs, such as wmic.exe?

Comment: @eryksun yes I'm trying to figure out if one of my prent processes are cmd or PS. But I'm trying to find a cleaner solution like environment variables. I don't want to exec any external programs as much as I can. If there's a simpler solution I'd like to go with that.

Comment: Getting the parent process ID and then its name is simple enough using WMI (wmic.exe), but what good does this do you? Are you instead interested to know whether you're attached to a console window (i.e. the window that's created and managed by conhost.exe) instead of detached or with standard I/O redirected to a pipe/file? If so, do you have something like [`_isatty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew.aspx) in your environment?

Answer (score 2):

Eryksun might have a point about the usefullness of this but there is a [post about getting the parent process](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b761fc16-4d41-45a8-a925-2c5ebef33112/how-to-get-parent-process-id).

Putting the following text into a ps1 script:

```
$parentpid=(gwmi win32_process -Filter "processid='$pid'").parentprocessid
Write-Host ("I am running in {0}" -f (Get-Process -id $parentpid).Name)
```

Running it from CMD calling PowerShell:

> I am running in cmd

Running it from PowerShell and ISE:

> I am running in explorer

So while explorer is not very useful it is not CMD which I think is what you actually wanted to know.

Comment: What do you mean "I am running in cmd"? Do you mean to determine that you are "running with an attached console window" (conhost.exe -- this has nothing to do with cmd.exe, which is just a shell program), and "standard I/O is currently directed to said console window" (instead of say, to a file)? Knowing the parent process doesn't help determine that at all.

Comment: @eryksun I most likely misinterpreted the question. If PowerShell was called from withing a CMD process is what the code was meant to determine

Comment: FWIW, ISE runs console programs with a hidden console window (you can show it via `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 5)` and leaves the process `StandardInput` attached to this console, but `StandardOutput` is set to a pipe, to allow it to display the program's output. Maybe that helps, but I don't know what the real problem is, if it even relates to ISE, or what's possible in the OP's environment (I've never programmed in Go).