# Determine whether programs run on Powershell or CMD

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, cmd

I created a program that should `rename` some files

```
system("rename file.txt file2.txt"); // examples only
```

did run fine at `cmd` , but not `powershell`

```
rename : The term 'rename' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ rename
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (rename:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

by [This article from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1) , `powershell` should use `rename-item`
However , I don't know any  "trick" to determine whther programs ran by `powershell` or `cmd`
A post [for determine program's run by which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323938/find-out-if-process-is-running-in-a-cmd-exe-or-powershell-window) , uses process checking which I find it hard to implement ( they said use `wmic.exe` , but I don't know how to and further research needed to be )

The conclusion:

> How to determine whether my programs runs on `powershell` or `cmd` by `C++` ?
>
> Is it possible, by knowing the console used ( programmingly ) , my programs could use `if-else` method to change the `command`?

Edit: for the time being , My program's method is read `file.txt` and paste it in `file2.txt` ( examples only )..Basically like `copy and paste` to another renamed file and use `system("del file.txt");`

Comment: Wouldn't that be based on how you created the program? I may be misunderstanding this.

Comment: It would be better for your code to `rename` files using c++ code. However I can see that determining what type of console you are running on top of may be useful.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I compiled using `g++ -o main.exe main.cpp` , since its a `executable` file , both `powershell` and `cmd` could run it

Comment: My first guess is checking the available environment variables passed to your application. I see in a cmd.exe window I have a `ComSpec` environment variable set to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`. Edit: Well its still set in powershell so no help sorry.

Comment: @drescherjm yea , as of right now , my `ComSpec` do set to `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`. Should I add another variable for `powershell.exe`?.

path :`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: I would probably wait for some other person to have a better suggestion. After looking at the environment for both powershell and cmd.exe I don't think this is a good automatic method

Comment: Could you use:
`if (system(NULL)) { system("rename file.txt file2.txt"); }
else {//Do something else.}`

Comment: Why do you run with `system()` the standard command processor of the operating system which is defined by the environment variable `ComSpec` to rename a file from within an executable coded in C++? There is the function [rename](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/) in `cstdio` for this purpose. There is also the function [remove](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) to delete a file in `cstdio`. What do you think which programming language was used to write `cmd.exe` called on Windows with `system()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to determine whether my programs runs on powershell or cmd by C++

While that is possible, it also *irrelevant* to your use case, because the shell that launched your program is your program's *parent* process (to which you cannot submit commands).

**Since your program must launch its *own* shell (child) process in order to execute a shell command, you're free to *choose* which shell to invoke .**

The **`system()` C library function targets the host platform's *default* shell**, which is **`cmd.exe`** on Windows (and `/bin/sh` on Unix-like platforms), so your command - which uses the internal `cmd.exe` `rename` command - will work fine, irrespective of whether your program was invoked from PowerShell or `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Wow , I really did not noticed that and worked out great. So I just wasted a minute or 2 to create the alternative .. Anyway , thanks